# Pokemon Bank Issue - Cannot save?

Tags: pokemon-bank

Pokemon Bank has recently been giving me issues: it refuses to save the game. I may have screwed myself over - I restarted my game. Now the bank keeps saying to use the non-existing file because it didn't save properly.

I have asked Pokemon.com for help, but that was about 2 weeks ago and I have heard nothing from them.

The Save fail Error Code I'm getting is 006-0112

Comment: Is the bank not letting you reconnect to your online box?  What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: did you try actually contacting Nintendo? they're pretty quick at replying

Comment: If you've found the solution, feel free to type up that solution in the answer section below, rather than editing it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the OP (originally posted in the question):

---

I found the solution for error code 006–0112; I think it's because I had the gifts and Pokémon link in the game. I collected the gift and now I can use the bank properly, I can save again.